# RelativeLayout : giving priority to a view

Tags: android

i will try to simplify as much as I can without changing the real xml:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtTitleDate"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"/>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/datePickerPager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtTitleDate"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtPriorityDate"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="50dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/datePickerPager"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layoutPriorityDate"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/txtPriorityDate"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">
  <!-- omitted -->
</LinearLayout>
```

Without the ViewPager, I had enough space to show the `LinearLayout` in the bottom. But this ends up with the `ViewPager` taking up more space than it should, and  flowing over the parent view.

How can i give priority to the `LinearLayout` to for the use of space without  any hardcoded size values?

Thanks.

Comment: how about using layoutWeight?

Comment: If you parent layout is LinearLayout, then you can use weights,, give higher weight to LinearLayout

Comment: @Murtaza Hussain it should be if parent is LinearLayout you can use weights.

Comment: yeah sorry. In Linear Layout only.

Comment: it s a RelativeLayout too

Comment: RelativeLayouts **don't use weights**, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this by using the `android:layout_weight` attribute from `LinearLayout`.

As explained on the [Linear Layout site from the API Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html):

> This attribute assigns an "importance" value to a view in terms of how
>   much space is should occupy on the screen. A larger weight value
>   allows it to expand to fill any remaining space in the parent view.
>   Child views can specify a weight value, and then any remaining space
>   in the view group is assigned to children in the proportion of their
>   declared weight. Default weight is zero.

In your case, nesting the other views in a LinearLayout would do the job:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtTitleDate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"/>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/datePickerPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtTitleDate"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtPriorityDate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="50dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/datePickerPager"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutPriorityDate"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/txtPriorityDate"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

You should test a bit with different values for the weights to fit your precise needs.